# How to use Watir (PhantomJS) to select on HTML ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, phantomjs, nokogiri, watir-webdriver

I am trying to use Watir (Phantom JS) to input a text in a textfield. But how can I select the textfield's ID if I am not just selecting on the class?

```
browser.text_field(id: "message").set     # would this work? or do I need
browser.text_field(name: "#message").set? # Can I drop the "#" ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="message" name="name">
```

By using an attribute of the `<input>` tag as a locator, you can input a string into the text_field.  For example, you could use one of the following:

```
b.text_field(id: "message").set "this is the message"
b.text_field(name: "name").set  "this is the name"
```

As far as I know, the `set?` method only works for checkboxes and radio buttons.  If you want to retrieve the string in the text_field, you could use the `value`method:

```
b.text_field(id: "message").set "this is the message"
puts b.text_field(id: "message").value
#=> this is the message
```